# ConcurrentHashmap prints empty

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrenthashmap

I am declaring the concurrent hashmap and adding elements into that in subsequent thread declarations. 
But still it is printing blank.
See the code below:

```js
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
   
  Employee obj = new Employee();
  
  Map<String, String> myMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();
  
  Thread T1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    myMap.put("Los", "angls");
    
   }
  });
  
  Thread T2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    myMap.put("new", "york");
    
   }
  });
 
  T1.start();
  T2.start();

     System.out.println(myMap); 
  
 }
```

what is the use of ConcurrentHashmap here ? If both Hashmap and ConcurrentHashmap can add the elements through threads ?

Comment: Is this all the code? You never start the threads. You also can't guarantee that they'll have run by the time the print happens.

Comment: you should start those threads somewhere, shouldn´t you?

Comment: what is the use of ConcurrentHashmap here ? If both Hashmap and ConcurrentHashmap can add the elements through threads ?

Comment: @user2746466 Because it isn't necessarily safe to do so with a non-concurrent implementation.

Comment: You can't guarantee that concurrent calls to the non-synchronized version won't mess with the internal state somehow, like messing with the internal size counter. Exactly how it can be messed up though depends on the specific implementation of the called methods and what time they're called in relation to each other.

Answer (score 1):

You are just creating two `Thread` objects, which are never started. You'll have to start them, and then wait for them to complete (e.g., by calling `join`):

```
T1.start();
T2.start();

T1.join();
T2.join();
```

Comment: I did still I am getting inconsistent output

Comment: @user2746466 You need to print after the calls to join.

Comment: what is the use of ConcurrentHashmap here ? If both Hashmap and ConcurrentHashmap can add the elements through threads ? 
Where is thread safety by ConcurrentHashmap ?